# toggle class bug on list items angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

How can I rewrite this code so that I toggle the class '.done' only on the element clicked, not on the whole 'li' collection? The result of the following code is that all elements are toggled with the .done class at the same time:

What I'm trying to do is mark the item done, when the a href with a star icon is clicked.

With javascript, I would do event.target or $(this).hide(), or similar. But I'm not sure how to do it with angular2

```
<div *ngIf="selectedSet">  
        <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item avatar" [ngClass]="{'done': isDone }" *ngFor='let set of newSetCollection;  #i = index; #last = last'>
                <img src="{{set.pic_left}}" alt="" class="circle">
                <div class="collection-content">
                    <span class="title">{{set.sets}} {{set.name}}</span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Effected:</th>
                            <td><span> {{set.MainMuscleWorked}}</span> <!--span>, Middle Back, Triceps</span--></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Use:</th>
                            <td><span>{{set.Equipment}}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="secondary-content" (click)="isDone = !isDone;"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage a field on the element in the loop instead:

```
<li class="collection-item avatar"
    [ngClass]="{'done': set.isDone }"
    *ngFor='let set of newSetCollection; let i = index; let last = last'>
```

and toggle this property like this:

```
<a href="#" class="secondary-content" (click)="set.isDone = !set.isDone;">
  <i class="material-icons">grade</i>
</a>
```

Otherwise things are global to all elements of your collection...

Answer (score 0):

The variable `done` is bound to the `Component` in which this template is used, not inside the list element. A solution could be to add an extra parameter to your `set` model and change your template to this:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedSet">  
   <ul class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item avatar" [class.done]="set.isDone" *ngFor='let set of newSetCollection;  #i = index; #last = last'>
          <img src="{{set.pic_left}}" alt="" class="circle">
              <div class="collection-content">
                  <span class="title">{{set.sets}} {{set.name}}</span>
                  <table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Effected:</th>
                        <td><span> {{set.MainMuscleWorked}}</span> <!--span>, Middle Back, Triceps</span--></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Use:</th>
                        <td><span>{{set.Equipment}}</span></td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
         <a href="#" class="secondary-content" (click)="set.isDone = !set.isDone"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a boolean flag, you can set the index and use it in `ngClass`:

```
    <div *ngIf="selectedSet">  
        <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item avatar" [ngClass]="{'done': isDone === i }" *ngFor='let set of newSetCollection;  #i = index; #last = last'>
                <img src="{{set.pic_left}}" alt="" class="circle">
                <div class="collection-content">
                    <span class="title">{{set.sets}} {{set.name}}</span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Effected:</th>
                            <td><span> {{set.MainMuscleWorked}}</span> <!--span>, Middle Back, Triceps</span--></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Use:</th>
                            <td><span>{{set.Equipment}}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="secondary-content" (click)="isDone = i"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Right :) If you want to maintain a state for each item then you need to add it to `set` or maintain an array of `isDone` outset of `newSetCollection`.